# How should I handle my Firebase dependency if Xcode recognizes "import Firebase", but doesn't recognize anything else? (SPM)

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, swift-package-manager, swift-package

I'm using XCode 14.2, and Swift Package Manager. I've imported Firebase version 10.14.0, with libaries FirebaseAnalytics and FireFirestore. However, XCode, does not recognizes statements such as FirebaseApp.configure(), and throws errors even when building, but acknowledges the module "Firebase" and "FirebaseFirestore" when I import them

I tried restarting XCode, deleting derived data, and clean building, also uninstalling and reinstalling firebase.

Comment: There could be a number of reasons for the issue but there's not enough info in the question to really provide much help. For example, if you're using Firebase Firestore, you would need to `#import FirebaseCore` and then `#import FirebaseFirestore`. We don't know which Firebase products you're using, and there are a number of them. Check out the getting started guide [Init Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#initialize)